# Can I program Watson Assistant to differentiate singular and plural in context variable "distance": 1 mile vs 2 miles?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Can I program Watson Assistant to differentiate singular and plural in context variable "distance": 1 mile vs 2 miles? I am new to writing code in Watson, I mostly handled simple cases of intents, entities and dialog nodes so far. I know that with Entities, you have to put in a separate synonym for plural. But not sure how to program it in context variables, and if it is even possible. Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do you want to output "mile" and "miles" or what do you mean with "differentiate"?

Comment: Hi @data_henrik

Comment: Hi @data_henrik. Thank you for your response. So my Watson is looking for particular service providers, for users. So it says something like "I found 3 providers, near zip-code on file. First provider is 1 mile away. Second provider is 2 miles away. Third provider is 6 miles away." So I want Watson to be able to recognize when provider is 1 mile away, and use singular - "mile". And recognize when provider is more than 1 mile away, and use plural - "miles". Today, as is, my Watson says "miles" for all providers. It says "This provider is 1 miles away." Hope this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could [add a check directly](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#conditions-and-predicates-in-the-response) into your response or when assigning parts of a response to a context variable. [Watson Assistant has a set of expressions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods) you could use.

Conceptually, do this:

- if num_miles==1 then output="1 mile"
- else output=num_miles+" miles"

As said, you could define a variable that already holds text snippets with the right wording and just return them in the response. Or you could add an expression to a response.